# How .NET managed assembly resolve its referencing native assembly / GAC

Tags: .net, clr, .net-assembly

Spot a really weird situation, so seeking for explanation:

```
System.Fabric.dll is managed assembly provided by Azure's Service Fabric.

FabricClient.dll is native assembly on which System.Fabric.dll relies.
```

[image: managed refering native]

SystemFabric Runtime is running on the VM with version 8.0. It has registered System.Fabric.dll into GAC with the same version 8.0. Along with this version *PublisherPolicy.7.0* is also registered which re-directs all 7.0 System.Fabric lookups on a VM to the 8.0 version from the GAC.

Executed test.exe (FabricClient.dll and System.Fabric.dll are shipped along with this test.exe) on a VM which has compiled using the 7.0 version of the System.Fabric.dll, and started hitting interop COM InvalidCastException.

Used procmon to debug why *.dlls are clashing and found that System.Fabric.dll was used with version 8.0 from the GAC because of the publisher policy, but FabricClient.dll was used from the local directory where is test.exe.

So far I know .NET resolves **managed** assemblies using following approach:

[image: clr resolve]

But what's the approach windows uses for resolving **native** assemblies?

Also is it expected that if managed assembly is reused from the GAC due to the policy, that the its pairing native dll is not reused from the windows subdir. (IIRC I have seen FabricClient.dll 8.0 registerd within Windows directory)

Seems like Windows firstly looks up for native dll in the same directory where test.exe resides?

Comment: Isn't it what's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications).

Comment: @PawełŁukasik yeah thanks, i've found it too. Gac and native resolvers simply do not follow the same approach and sometimes it can cause applications to crash (managed and native dlls version mismatch).